# Python and Floats - Print only the Whole Number

Tags: c++, python, floating-point

Is there a way in Python to print only the whole number portion of a float when no additional precision is required to express the number? For example, the float 1.0. Some other languages do this by default. Here are some examples:

In C++, this code prints 1, not 1.0:

```
int main()
{ 
    float f = 1.0;
    std::cout << f << "\n";

    return 0;
}

./a.out 
1
```

However, in Python, this code prints 1.0:

```
f = 1.0

print type(f)
<type 'float'>

print f
1.0
```

I'd like for the Python code to only print 1, not 1.0, when that's all that is required to fully represent the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `g` formatting option:

```
f = 1.0
print(f"{f:g}")           # Python 3.6 and above
```

or

```
print "{:g}".format(f)
```

or

```
print "%g" % f
```

This does something very similar to `std::cout` in default configuration.  It will only print a limited number of digits, just like `std::cout`.

Comment: That's so simple. It works like I want too. When additional precision needs to be expressed, it does so. Thank you.

Comment: In your examples, you do not include f anyplace, thus I need to do more digging for the answer.

Comment: For python 3 with f-strings: `print(f"{val:g}")`, where `val` is your variable

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator should work across all Python versions:

```
>>> f = 1.0
>>> if f % 1 == 0:
...     print int(f)
... else:
...     print f
... 
1
>>>
```